# Remove null values from collection

Tags: c#, automapper

We commonly have the use case that we have collections with one null element inside (`new SomeType[]{null}`). Right now we have an extension method that removes these null elements, but obviously we have to configure it for each collection we want to map.

Is there some generic way to tell automapper to remove null-values from collections, either globally or per profile?

Comment: Are those collections the root elements for mapping or are they somewhere in an embedded member?

Comment: @bommelding can be both, but it does not really matter as we don't want to manually configure a mapping for each collection. I.e. we are looking for a generic solution that would apply to all collections / IEnumerables.

Answer (score 1):

AotoMapper provides [Condition](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html?highlight=condition) mapping

For exemple,

```
CreateMap<MyClassDTO, MyClass>()
     .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
```

On in the global level (not tested)

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, map) =>
        map.ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
}
```

Comment: yes but this only applies to a specific mapping, right ?